# GGTS groovy class error message

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-tool-suite

I am using GGTS Version: 3.4.0.RELEASE IDE. and configured with Grails-2.3.4.
When I create test groovy class its giving error in the first line. show this error message.

now sure where its getting Groovy 1.8.6

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Groovy:Unexpected problem with AST transform: The Spock compiler plugin cannot execute because Spock 0.7.0-groovy-2.0 is not compatible with Groovy 1.8.6. For more information, see http://versioninfo.spockframework.org  Gekki.groovy    /hello/src/groovy/test  line 0  Java Problem
```

How can I fix this error message?

Edit:

I tried this still same issue

http://grails.org/plugin/spock

my version

```
Grails version: 2.3.4
Groovy version: 2.1.9
JVM version: 1.7.0_45
```

Comment: Either use a groovy version >= 2.0 or choose a spock version that is compatible with Groovy 1.8.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings, I tried that still now luck

Comment: Checkout the Groovy version configured in the IDE (not project, but ide properties), maybe it's 1.8.x

Comment: @SérgioMichels, thanks for the tips. I need to switch groovy version in the IDE level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SérgioMichels suggested I need to enable groovy 2.0 compatiable.

thanks for every one tips.